# How to support multi-language in nodejs koa2 and ejs

Tags: javascript, node.js, ejs, koa2

I try to write a web page, and it should support multi-language, in `index.js`

```
const Koa = require('koa');
const views = require('koa-views');
const path = require('path');
app.use(views(path.join(__dirname, './view'), {
    extension: 'ejs'
}));

app.use( async ( ctx ) => {
let title;
//some codes
if(language == "en") { //if the language is English
    title="Title";
}
else if(language == "de") { //if the language is German
    title="Titel";
}
await ctx.render('index', {
    title
});
});
app.listen(3000, ()=>{
  console.log('app runs on port 3000');
});
```

And the `index.ejs`

```
 <%=title%>
```

and I run this code, it will show well, and now I want to add a language package, such as `language.json` to this project

```
{
"en":  {
    "site":  {
        "title":  "Title"
    }
},
"de": {
    "site":  {
        "title":  "Titel"
    }
 }
}
```

So how should I change in `index.js` and `index.ejs`?

Answer (score 2, accepted):

```
const Koa = require('koa');
const views = require('koa-views');
const path = require('path');
app.use(views(path.join(__dirname, './view'), {
    extension: 'ejs'
}));



const siteTitleLibrary = {
"en":  {
    "site":  {
        "title":  "Title"
    }
},
"de": {
    "site":  {
        "title":  "Titel"
    }
 }
};
// or 
// const siteTitleLibrary = require('language.json');

app.use( async ( ctx ) => {
await ctx.render('index', {
  site: siteTitleLibrary[language]
});
});
app.listen(3000, ()=>{
  console.log('app runs on port 3000');
});
```

then in your ejs use `<%=site.title%>`

Comment: Thank you so much.

Comment: Thank you very much. Your answer was the only one found on Google search...